# Why does Thunderbird permanently asks to "verify xb7481.xb7.serverdomain.org:143"?

Tags: email, thunderbird, ssl

After using Thunderbird for 5+ years now, I suddenly get this weird popup asking to "Verify this security exception rule" [translated from german].

This happens without any reason, without looking at any message, even with a completely empty inbox, without any user action. "serverdomain.org" looks like a placeholder btw.

Searching for "serverdomain.org" does not give any useful results. Weird.

Comment: This looks like an oddball type of problem (Thunderbird, not you), that doesn't appear to be widespread (couldn't find anything similar with an online search).  It looks like corruption.  When I've run into strange problems with Mozilla products, I've had luck at their support web site: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/products/thunderbird.  They have a forum, also, with some people with in-depth product knowledge.